# Solving Bethe ansatz equations

Tags: equation-solving, nonlinear, procedural-programming

I'm very new to Mathematica. I want to solve the Bethe ansatz equations for the so-called "Hofstadter-problem". These equations take the form:

$$z^2_{l}=q^{Q} \prod^{Q-1}_{\substack{m=1\\m \neq l}}\frac{q^2 z_{l}-z_{m}}{z_{l}-q^2 z_{m}}$$

for

$$l=1,...,Q-1$$

where $q$ is a complex number given by

$\qquad q=e^{i \pi \frac{P}{Q}}$

where $\frac{P}{Q}$ is the magnetic flux and $Q$ is an integer.

I want to solve these equations for $Q=1,2,3,\ldots$,

Does anyone has some ideas? Please, I really need some help.

```
Q = 2, 3, 4, ....

u0 = 
  Do[FindRoot[
    Subscript[z, l]^2 == 
     q^Q*Product[(q^2 Subscript[z, l] - Subscript[z, m])/(Subscript[z,
           l] - q^2 Subscript[z, m]), {m, 1, Q - 1}], 
    WorkingPrecision -> 50, AccuracyGoal -> 20]; 

 ListPlot[Transpose[{u0 // Re, u0 // Im}], 
   PlotRange -> All, 
   AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

Comment: @Dennbert Edit your question, copy/paste the _Mathematica_ code, select it and press the curly braces {}.

Comment: I put your equation in between "$$" so TeX renders properly. But you have a mismatch "[" so please edit and correct. I would be good if you ADD Mathematica code and keep the TeX equation too.

Comment: Don't you still have to exclude $l$ from your product in the Mma code? Either use `Product[...,{m,Drop[Range[Q-1],l]}]` or `Product[...,{m,l-1}] Product[...,{m,l+1,Q-1}]`. (If this is not what you mean please edit the *LaTeX* formula.)

Comment: Recent edits to the question by the poster make existing answers obsolete.  I rolled it back so the existing answers make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a direct method for generating the equations and finding a root:

```
Clear[z,eqns,solution]
eqns[p_, Q_Integer?Positive] := With[{q = Exp[I \[Pi] p/Q]},
  Thread[
    Array[z, Q - 1]^2 == 
      q^Q *Times @@ 
        Array[KroneckerDelta[#1, #2] + (1 - KroneckerDelta[#1, #2]) (
         q^2 z[#2] - z[#1])/(z[#2] - q^2 z[#1]) &, {Q - 1, Q - 1}]
  ]
];

solution[p_?NumericQ, Q_Integer?Positive] := 
 Block[{z},
  FindRoot[
    Evaluate @ eqns[p, Q], 
    Evaluate @ Transpose[{Array[z, Q - 1], ConstantArray[1 + 0.01 I, Q - 1]}]]
];
```

Example solution:

```
sol = solution[0.5, 3]

Out[42]= {z[1] -> 0.707107 - 0.707107 I, z[2] -> 0.707107 - 0.707107 I}
```

**Edit: plotting the points on the unit circle**

```
ListPlot[
 Transpose @ Through[{Re, Im}[sol[[All, 2]]]], 
 PlotRange -> 1.1 {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}},
 Epilog -> {Dashed, Circle[]},
 AspectRatio -> 1
]
```

From this plot, it's clear that the points seem to coincide for the solutions my code is producing. This probably has something to do with my initial guess `ConstantArray[1 + 0.01 I, Q - 1]`. If you need different solutions, try different initial guesses, such as `Array[Exp[0.9 I \[Pi] #/Q] &, Q - 1]`.

**Another edit**
Here's a second solution function based on `NSolve`. It should give you all possible solutions, but it's probably going to be very slow for larger values of `Q`:

```
solution2[p_?NumericQ, Q_Integer?Positive] := 
 Block[{z}, NSolve[Evaluate@eqns[p, Q], Array[z, Q - 1]]]

sol2 = solution2[0.5, 3]

Out[52]= {{z[1] -> 0.28229 + 1.48894 I, 
  z[2] -> 0.648315 + 0.122915 I}, {z[1] -> -0.28229 - 1.48894 I, 
  z[2] -> -0.648315 - 0.122915 I}, {z[1] -> 0.707107 - 0.707107 I, 
  z[2] -> 0.707107 - 0.707107 I}, {z[1] -> -0.707107 + 0.707107 I, 
  z[2] -> -0.707107 + 0.707107 I}, {z[1] -> -0.648315 - 0.122915 I, 
  z[2] -> -0.28229 - 1.48894 I}, {z[1] -> 0.648315 + 0.122915 I, 
  z[2] -> 0.28229 + 1.48894 I}, {z[1] -> 0.707107 + 0.707107 I, 
  z[2] -> -0.707107 - 0.707107 I}, {z[1] -> -0.707107 - 0.707107 I, 
  z[2] -> 0.707107 + 0.707107 I}}
```

Plot the solutions:

```
ListPlot[
 Transpose[Through[{Re, Im}[#]]] & /@ sol2[[All, All, 2]], 
 PlotRange -> 1.1 {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}},
 Epilog -> {Dashed, Circle[]},
 AspectRatio -> 1
 ]
```

Comment: Yes, that is correct. You put in your magnetic flux `p` (I used a lower case p, but you can change that) and your integer `Q` and you get the solution. Because `FindRoot` is numeric, you need a numeric value for `p`. On another note: if this answer was helpful to you, could you upvote it and/or give it the "accept" check mark?

Comment: So your solution agrees with the solution from the code, right? `-2.18297*10^-16 + 1. I` is very nearly `I`, up to some numerical noise. Don't forget that Mathematica uses a capital `I` for the imaginary unit. Also keep in mind that `FindRoot` only finds one possible solution. If there are more, you need to try different initial search points.

Answer (score 4):

This is too long for a comment, so let me post it as an answer. **Note** that the following references pertain to the (slightly more complicated) Bethe-ansatz equations (BAE) for the Heisenberg XXX chain, but I hope and think it should help you.

Firstly, the introduction to the Bethe ansatz by Karbach and Muller goes into some detail as to how to solve the BAE numerically. There are three parts to *Introduction to the Bethe ansatz*: [arXiv:cond-mat/9809162](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/9809162), [arXiv:cond-mat/9809163](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/9809163), and, together with Hu, [arXiv:cond-mat/0008018](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0008018). This is not about *Mathematica* specifically, but does help tackling the problem by rewriting the BAE in a useful way.

More specifically the [*Mathematica Summer School on Theoretical Physics*](http://msstp.org/) has some useful material available; see in particular the material for [Day 2 of the first edition (2009)](http://msstp.org/?q=node/4) and [Day 1](http://msstp.org/?q=node/270) and [Day 2 of the fourth edition (2012)](http://msstp.org/?q=node/271) for numerical solutions of the BAE.

Finally, if you are willing to learn some computational algebraic geometry you might be able to adapt the work of Jiang and Zhang, *Algebraic geometry and Bethe ansatz (I) the quotient ring for BAE* [arXiv:1710.04693](https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.04693). To the best of my knowledge this is the most efficient way to solve the BAE to date. (There's also Marboe and Volin, *Fast analytic solver of rational Bethe equations* [arXiv:1608.06504](https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.06504), but that might rely too much on the algebraic structure sitting behind the Heisenberg model to apply to your case.)